# Is there any plugin for chrome which shows which function/method is triggered onclick of an element?

Tags: jquery

Iam working on vtiger there are bulk of jquery files and hundreds of methods at different locations.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the page, click "Inspect," and notice in the developer tools, to the far right (if the dev tools window opens up on the bottom) or the under the inspection window (if aligned to the right), next to "Styles", "Computed," and "Accessibility," there is a tab labeled "Event Listeners."  This tab should give you the information you're looking for.  "Onclick" is included in the list of event listeners.

Comment: I got what you are saying but  there are number of files under onclick can not distinguish actual method among all

Comment: A lot of times frameworks will come with their own debugging tools if the package is big enough.  Have you looked at their debugging documentation found [here](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Developer_Debug_Techniques)?